# regsub -all specfic replace with space

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using regsub to replace (T|Z) with space

```
set date(1,2) "2012-09-14T00:00:00Z"
regsub -all {(T|Z)} $date(1,2) " " date(1,2)
puts $date(1,2)
```

but when I am using

```
regsub -all {(T|Z)} $date(1,2) "\s" date(1,2)
```

it is replacing T|Z with \s .

How to map single space character to "\s" for code to look clearly

Comment: So, what's the problem? Doesn't `" "` work?
`"\s"` is a _Whitespace character class_ (spaces, tabs, line breaks). You can't replace something with the `"\s"` class, only with the exact string. (How is the system supposed to know what character you mean with `"\s"`?)

Comment: Even supposing Tcl was going to interpret the `\s` as a character class, which member of the class would it use? Space? Tab? Newline? Something more unusual? (There's actually quite a few…) The real problem is that you've not worked out what you actually want to do…

Comment: For very simple replacements like this `string map` is a better choice: `set date(1,2) [string map {T { } Z { }} $date(1,2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `"\s"` with `" "`

- `\s` : can mean many things, depending on the context. In the context of a regexp, and if the regexp interpretor knows about it, it should mean on a unix-type program "any whitespace character (space, or tab, or whatever else is ok as a whitespace in the current locale and LC_LANG)". So it would **match** any of those. On the "replace" side, however, it can't be known which is needed (space? tab? another?) so it can't be interpreted on that side, and tcl puts it "as is".